# Token value as a filter for Drupal View

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views, token

I am trying to make a view such that it will bring a type of content based on logged in user name. I have added username as a vocabulary term to all content. Now I want to filter the content based on logged in user name via filters available in View. For this I am trying to use token module.

Now my views are coming empty, which probably means that token module is not working. So my question is that can we use token along with View Filter and if yes, how.

Thanks

Comment: as far as I understand, there is no way to add token to view argument

Answer (score 5):

You don't need the token module. You should be able to do this with views arguments:

- Add a new argument "**User: Name**".
- Under "*Action to take if argument is not present*" select "**Provide default argument**".
- Under "*Provide default argument options*" select "**User ID from logged in user**"

Comment: I will try that. For knowledge, can we use tokens with View Filters ?

Comment: I don't think so, I could be wrong. Where would the token come from?

Comment: Can you explain this more? I'm using drupal 7 and views 3, and I don't find a way to add a new argument.